# How can I automatically create a folder in file explorer?

Tags: python

I want to automatically create three folders namely: CSV, image and PNG folder. I have a 'path' where the files are located. But when I try creating the folders using the 'path', it shows an error. I am practicing using a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gs0FNQR0njI&list=PLUaB-1hjhk8GnKlCG7I-I1tGxiB46SPWA&index=2&t=557s).

Create folders:

```
folder_names = ['csv files', 'image files', 'text files']

for loop in range(0,3):
    if not os.path.exists(path = folder_names[loop]):
        print(folder_names[loop])
        os.makedirs(folder_names[loop])
```

Error message:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[83], line 7
> 5 for loop in range(0,3):
> 6     if not os.path.exists(path = folder_names[loop]):
> ----> 7         print(path = folder_names[loop])
> 8         os.makedirs(path = folder_names[loop])
>
> TypeError: 'path' is an invalid keyword argument for print()

Comment: Your code doesn't match the exception. After you made the change to `print(folder_names[loop])`, does it work?

Comment: Seems like you didn't save the code before executing this version.

Comment: Like they said, your code doesn't match the error message you posted. `TypeError: 'path' is an invalid keyword argument for print()` indicates that you ran something like `print(path="...")`, which is not valid in Python because `print()` does not take an argument called `path`. However the print statement in your code is valid and should run, so we will need to see the latest version of your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me

```
import os

folder_names = ['a_dir', 'b_dir', 'c_dir']   # list of folders to create

for fn in folder_names:                      # run through the list
    if not os.path.exists(path = fn):        # check whether the folder alraedy exists
        print('create: ' ,fn)               
        os.makedirs(fn)                      # if not then create the folder
    else: print(fn, ' alraed exists')        # otherwise do nothing than to inform
```